# Python "Undefined variable 'flavours" pylint

Tags: python, list, class, methods

There's a problem with this code. Pylint is saying "flavours is an undefined variable" but I've declared it in **init** that inherits from the Restaurant class? Can somebody help please? What am I missing?

```
class Restaurant:
""" A class representing a restaurant """
def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
    """ Initialize the restaurant """
    self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
    self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

def describe_restaurant(self):
    """ A method to print the basic information about the restaurant """
    print (f"{self.restaurant_name}")
    print (f"{self.cuisine_type}")

def open_restaurant(self):
    """ Prints a message saying the restaurant is open """
    print (f"{self.restaurant_name} is open!")

class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
    """ A class representing an ice cream stand. Inherits attributes from the Restaurant class """

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type="Ice Cream"):
        """ Initialize an ice cream stand ""
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
        self.flavours = []

    def display_flavours(self):
        """ Display flavours available """
        print (f"\nThe current flavour offerings are: ")
        for flavour in self.flavours:
            print("- " + flavours.title())

 icecreamstand1 = IceCreamStand("Joel's Ice Cream")
 icecreamstand1.flavours = ["Mint", "Chocolate", "Vanilla"]

 icecreamstand1.describe_restaurant()
 icecreamstand1.display_flavours()
```

Comment: Please fix the comments in the code, and show us the line it's giving you the error.

Comment: Was it complaining about `print("- " + flavours.title())`? That should be `flavour.title()`.

Comment: If this was your actual code it wouldn't run at all. You don't properly close the docstring for `IceCreamStand.__init__`.

Comment: Didn't pylint report the line with the problem? The actual error message from pylint helps us figure the quesiton out. Since pylint tends to be chatty, you can trim it to the little bit that is relevant, but still, you are making us look for stuff that is already in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your for loop:

```
for flavour in self.flavours:
            print("- " + flavour.title())
```

It said `flavours.title()`

Comment: Ah I'm so dumb! Thank you!